# PIL Install issues - seems like I may be missing some required libs, but which ones and how to install?

Tags: python, installation, python-imaging-library

I had an error uploading images on my Python/Django site, and so installed the PIL library (1.1.6 on python 2.4 with CentOS) and also installed the jpeg library using $ sudo yum install freetype freetype-devel jpeg jpeg-devel libpng libpng-devel and the pil library using wget http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz

After unpacking, and running: python setup.py build_ext -i and sudo python setup.py install

I get an long string of errors, but they end in (previous ones are all about error: expected attribute etc...) :

```
_imaging.c:3041: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before        âfunctionsâ
_imaging.c:3138: warning: return type defaults to âintâ
_imaging.c: In function âDL_EXPORTâ:
_imaging.c:3138: error: expected declaration specifiers before âinit_imagingâ
_imaging.c:3149: error: expected â{â at end of input
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Please let me know if more of the errors messages are required to properly troubleshoot.

Comment: did you try installing pillow instead?

Comment: [pillow](http://pythonpackages.com/info/pillow) is a fork of PIL that makes it easy to install. Other than that, it's PIL.

Comment: what version of gcc are you using?

Comment: gcc version is gcc-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1. I'll have to try out Pillow....